# Output to_csv has one column

Tags: python, pandas

I made two columns, and exported them to CSV. I open the file, and there the values are divided by lines, BUT all in one column. I.e. in each line - "index, value1, value2". What could be the problem?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns = ['value1', 'value2'])
df.index += 1
print(df.dtypes)
filename2 = 'test2.csv'
df.to_csv(filename2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5BP1.png)

Comment: Maybe you should open it with a better software than excel? This is an Excel issue, not a pandas issue

Comment: As above, look into something like [view csv in Excel](https://planergy.com/blog/open-csv-in-excel/) if you must view it in excel

Comment: what version of excel are you using? I am unable to reproduce your issue

Comment: i am using excel version 19. next, I will read the article from the second comment

Comment: Yes, I really found the answer in this article. My mistake was that I opened the cvs file simply using excel, as windows suggested. However, it was necessary to import in the Data tab in Excel

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I really found the answer in this article(https://planergy.com/blog/open-csv-in-excel/). My mistake was that I opened the cvs file simply using excel, as windows suggested. However, it was necessary to import in the Data tab in Excel